# Failure to import a typescript interface from a sibling folder in my src directory using svelte and vite

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to import an interface, the first one, into my svelte project.

In `src/interface/EnabledSignUpArgs.interface.ts` there is this code

```
export interface EnabledSignupArgs {
  email: string
  username: string
  password: string
  confirmedPassword: string
  agreedToTOS: boolean
  agreedToPrivacyPolicy: boolean
}

// i also tried adding this
export default EnabledSignupArgs
```

In 2 files I am trying to

```
import { EnabledSignupArgs } from "../../interface/EnabledSignUpArgs.interface"
```

and

```
import { EnabledSignupArgs } from "../interface/EnabledSignUpArgs.interface"
```

*according to my IDE, this is fine* but the html the server spits out includes

> The requested module `'/src/interface/EnabledSignUpArgs.interface.ts'` does not provide an export named `EnabledSignupArgs`

I have tried: (1) restarting my dev server (2) moving the file to a different directory (3) making it a default export, but I am out of ideas!

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "DOM"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "$components/*": ["src/lib/components/*"],
      "$styles/*": ["src/lib/styles/*"],
      "$utils/*": ["src/lib/utils/*"],
      "$src/*": ["src/*"],
      "$lib": ["src/lib"],
      "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
    },
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.svelte"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Asking did the trick. Solution:

```
import type { interfaceName } from "../path/to/interface"
```